# Directly input "duration" data type into Numbers formula

Tags: numbers

I am trying to create a formula in Numbers which takes a duration and calculates what percentage this is of another duration.

For example, I have a duration of `1h 30m` in cell A1. I want to calculate what this is as a percentage of 9h. I am trying to output 17%.

I tried diving the cell A1 by 9, but this (rightfully) outputs a duration as A1 is being divided by a number. I need to divide A1 by another duration (i.e. 9h) in order to get a fraction. Is it possible to do this directly in the formula? The only other way I can how to do it is by inputing a duration of `9h` into cell B2, and then writing `=A1/B2`. However, I would prefer being able to avoid using the auxiliary cell B2 when performing this calculation.

Comment: great question pretty sure this also works in excel

Comment: @JBis thanks! It definitely should. Also probably with addition, subtraction, maybe even modular arithmetic!

Comment: Glad I could help! I learned something too. Didn't know Excel/Numbers could use math with durations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Divide by text in quotes.**

So if you want to divide `A1` which contain `"1h 30m"` by `"9m"` then use the following function `A1 ÷ "9m"` (`A1` contains `"1h 30m"`). This is the equivalent of putting `"9m"` in `B1` and then in using the function `"A1 ÷ B1"` in `C3`: Both will give you `10` because 9 minutes goes into 1 hour 3 min 10 times.

[image]